# Spring Boot Email template path issue

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot App on that users can register and app sends validation email to user for being registered. There is AbstractEmailContext that I code following a tutorial on web. Also I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk to distribute app. Problem is, while testing on local machine database and email sending works correctly. After uploading to Elasticbeanstalk email sending gives error because setTemplateLocation parameter can not find "confirm.html" template.

Here AbstracEmailVerification class,

```
public class AccountVerificationEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext{

    private String token;

    @Override
    public <T> void init(T context){
        CCUser ccUser = (CCUser) context;
        put("name", ccUser.getName());
        setTemplateLocation("/confirm");
        setSubject("Complete your registration!");
        setFrom("no_reply@crosscheck.tech");
        setTo(ccUser.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void rinit(T context){
        CCUser ccUser = (CCUser) context;
        put("email", ccUser.getEmail());
        setTemplateLocation("/creset");
        setSubject("Change your Password!");
        setFrom("no_reply@crosscheck.tech");
        setTo(ccUser.getEmail());
    }

    public void setToken(String token){
        this.token = token;
        put("token", token);
    }

    public void buildVerificationUrl(final String baseUrl, final String token){
        final String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl).path("/registration/verify").queryParam("token",token).toUriString();
        put("verificationURL",url);
    }

    public void buildResetUrl(final String baseUrl, final String token){
        final String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl).path("/forgotpass/resetpass").queryParam("token",token).toUriString();
        put("verificationURL",url);
    }
}
```

And method to send email,

```
@Override
public void sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(CCUser user){
    ConfirmationToken secureToken = secureTokenService.createSecureToken();
    secureToken.setUserToken(user);
    secureTokenRepository.save(secureToken);
    AccountVerificationEmailContext emailContext = new AccountVerificationEmailContext();
    emailContext.init(user);
    emailContext.setToken(secureToken.getConfirmationToken());
    emailContext.buildVerificationUrl(baseUrl, secureToken.getConfirmationToken());
    try {
        emailService.sendMail(emailContext);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I could not find correct path while app works on AWS Elasticbeanstalk for setTemplateLocation parameter. Please advice about subject.

Also the error,

```
Feb  4 22:18:25 ip-10-0-10-120 web[517963]: 2024-02-04T22:18:25.691Z ERROR 517963 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [src/resources/templates/confirm], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
Feb  4 22:18:25 ip-10-0-10-120 web[517963]: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [src/resources/templates/confirm], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra "/" in front of "confirm" parameter. I have removed it and now email method is working.